# Where can I find a repository of open data stories?

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data

Stories that highlight the impact of open data and connect data to the individual. They can be small and regional.

Comment: will update and create a comprehensive answer, when we have more.

Answer (score 4):

Alright, some links!

- This was started years ago, but didn't seem to take off: http://opendatastories.org/
- Before the Beyond Transparency book, CfA did Engagement Stories: http://commons.codeforamerica.org/engagement-commons (The Commons hasn't been getting a ton of love recently though)
- OKF has a (more recent) living doc exploring how open data improved data quality: http://bit.ly/opendata-betterdata

Answer (score 4):

For stories about companies and groups successfully using open data in the United States, there are two sources:

- [Highlights on Data.gov](http://highlights.data.gov) -- these are companies, civil society groups, non-profits, and citizens using open government data
- [The Open Data 500](http://www.opendata500.com/) -- this is a collection of 500 companies that have built a business model on open data (both government and non-government data)

(Disclaimer: I am the Evangelist for Data.gov.)

Answer (score 3):

There's Code For America's e-book [Beyond Transparency](http://beyondtransparency.org/)

Comment: Yes, but it's not really a "living document".

Comment: yes it is, you can fork it and edit it https://github.com/codeforamerica/beyondtransparency

Answer (score 3):

You could also take a look at [data.gov.uk case studies](http://data.gov.uk/library/?f%5B0%5D=im_field_document_type:85) which has 69 case studies of open data use across the UK, it may help extrapolate some scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

You should check the new project of Open Knowledge Foundation about community stories.

http://okfncommunity.tumblr.com

Answer (score 3):

Check out [www.dataforgood.io](http://www.dataforgood.io/), a platform for sharing data-driven projects for social good. It's maybe the first crowdsourced directory of such projects. Anyone can post.

There are not only open data projects, but you can find them by choosing the [open data category](http://www.dataforgood.io/category/open-data).

Answer (score 2):

You can find some examples of the impact of specific kinds of open data in Sunlight's "Data Deep Dives" -- I'm part of the local policy team working on these, and I'd be happy to help answer any questions!

http://sunlightfoundation.com/policy/local/

Answer (score 2):

Check out their database of databases at http://www.quandl.com/

Answer (score 2):

sunlight foundation just published their report highlighting 100 cases of social impact, which can be picked through to find economic benefits http://sunlightfoundation.com/blog/2015/05/05/a-new-approach-to-measuring-the-impact-of-open-data/

Answer (score 1):

[Dan Nguyen a former news application developer at ProPublica](http://www.propublica.org/site/author/dan_nguyen), taught a data journalism class at NYU during the fall of 2013. He compiled a list of data journalism related articles.

A large amount of these stories were born out of public data and FOIA requests, but not all. From the list description:

> This is a list of both useful and eclectic articles and guides to data journalism, in no particular order, though I’ve sorted them into rough categories for now. This list is auto-generated from a Google Spreadsheet

[Small Data Journalism Readings](http://www.smalldatajournalism.com/readings/)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the [Open Data 500](http://www.opendata500.com/) project from GovLab, which collects companies that rely on open data to create products and services.

Answer (score 1):

This question highlights organizations that successfully use open data:

- [successful open data advocacy website](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4425/successful-open-data-advocacy-website)

These organizations publish many case studies that fit your request very well.